# Facebook log-in in macOS "Internet Accounts" suddenly stopped working

Tags: settings, system-settings, accounts, facebook

As of about a week or two ago, I started getting notifications in macOS (High Sierra, 10.13.4 17E202) that I need to sign in again ("Facebook Password Required"). It seems to accept my (definitely correct) password but then a moment later it asks for it again and I cannot get Facebook features like photo sharing to work at all.

I have not had this problem in other Internet Accounts (e.g. Twitter)

On the basis of answers here and online I tried removing and re-adding it, removing all Facebook related items in my login Keychain, and using an app-specific password.

I noticed that Facebook has updated its security settings page a lot, I suspect because of GDPR… So maybe they actually broke logging in from macOS? It seems unlikely, albeit possible, so I figured I'd ask on here to see if anyone has another solution or is experiencing the same issue as of late.

Note, if I look at my activity in security settings on Facebook it shows all these logins but it's from an unknown device.

---

Edit:
Marked as a duplicate?… as I stated in the question this seems to be a new issue and previous answers don't seem to help. Seems to be specific to Facebook.

Comment: Farcebork demands actual sign in every time you go there now. Type it in a browser, you'll see a login page that never used to happen. idk quite what changed, & I don't go there often enough to have investigated fully.

Comment: @Tetsujin, what are you referring to? On the browser? Not seeing that at all.

Comment: Just anecdotal, but I've noticed this problem for quite a lot of savvy users.

Comment: Which, the one in my post, or the one @Tetsujin is referring to?

Comment: Two other people I know have said they are having the same problem.

Comment: @shim The one in your post.